# get data from json and send it to chart after split it

Tags: javascript, json, apexcharts

hallo everyone in my project I parse JSON file from API online and I stop in a split because
I don't know to split it and search more and more on youtube but not find what I need it to try to function and not work "I'm new in javascript" the JSON file like this

```
"timeline": {
"cases": {
"8/29/21": 1874435,
"8/30/21": 1881213,
"8/31/21": 1888150,
"9/1/21": 1895459,
"9/2/21": 1902407,
```

and I need to send to chart

https://apexcharts.com/ this is chart what I use it

```
 
    dayno = 30; 
url = "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/historical/iraq?lastdays=" + dayno; 
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  redirect: 'follow'
};
// .then(result => console.log(result.timeline.cases)
const {cases}= timeline;
fetch(url, requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => console.log(result.timeline.cases))
 
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));


  var options = {
    chart: {
      height: 280,
      type: "area"
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: "Series 1",
        data: [45, 52, 38, 45, 19, 23, 2] // number of cases after split it
      }
    ],
    fill: {
      type: "gradient",
      gradient: {
        shadeIntensity: 1,
        opacityFrom: 0.7,
        opacityTo: 0.9,
        stops: [0, 90, 100]
      }
    },
    xaxis: {
      categories: [
        "01 Jan", // date her form split 
        "02 Jan",
        "03 Jan",
        "04 Jan",
        "05 Jan",
        "06 Jan",
        "07 Jan"
      ]
    }
  };
  
  var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
  
  chart.render();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it's simple date chart you shouldn't use categories in your `xaxis`.

In this case it is preferred to use `type: "datetime"`.

```
xaxis : { type: 'datetime' }
```

In fetch you have to format data that you've got.

```js
fetch(url, requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
  let tempSerie = {name: 'cases', data: []}
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(result.cases)) {
  tempSerie.data.push([key, value]);
  }
  chart.updateSeries([tempSerie]);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

You create temporary series variable in which you save object with name `cases` and empty data array.

Next you iterate through properties of object you've got and push a data array with new `[key, value]` array.

At the end you update chartSeries.

Comment: how to push more data to chart i try to add deaths but doesn't work or not rendering

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code as below. Please check if this helps. You can use javascript `Object.keys` to get the key of objects and `Object.values` to get the values of the json object.

```
dayno = 30; 
url = "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/historical/iraq?lastdays=" + dayno; 
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  redirect: 'follow'
};
// .then(result => console.log(result.timeline.cases)
const {cases}= timeline;

fetch(url, requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => console.log(result.timeline.cases))
 
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

const series1 = Object.values(cases);
const dates = Object.keys(cases);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      height: 280,
      type: "area"
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: "Series 1",
        data: series1 // number of cases after split it
      }
    ],
    fill: {
      type: "gradient",
      gradient: {
        shadeIntensity: 1,
        opacityFrom: 0.7,
        opacityTo: 0.9,
        stops: [0, 90, 100]
      }
    },
    xaxis: {  
      categories: dates // date her form split
    }
  };
  
  var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
  
  chart.render();
```